# replace regex match with lines from an external file

Tags: regex, perl

Using Perl, I am parsing through a text file and would like to find a keyword and filename, then I need to open that file (it is in the same directory as the file being parsed), take the text from it, and insert it after the match.

file1 = file being parsed

file2 = file to include

Example of the two files in the beginning:

```
file1
code code code
%include file2;
code code code

file2
(* a bunch of header information *)
function ( arg : type);
```

And what I would like file1 to look like after:

```
file1
code code code
(*%include file2;*)
(* a bunch of header information *)
function ( arg : type);
code code code
```

I need help developing the perl to perform this replace.

I have the following written that takes the file to be parsed and reads it as a string. I would like to keep this method as I have already implemented several replaces using it, but the rest is open season. I like to understand things as well so if you would not mind a brief explanation of the submitted solution it would be appreciated.

```
#keep this part
open FILEHANDLE, "<", $file or die $!;
$string = do { local $/; <FILEHANDLE> };

#several other replace operations here already written
$string ~= s/match/replace;

#can rewrite this to be anything that works well
#match the include tag
if ($string =~ m/^%include\s+'(\w+).(PRO)'/gi)
{
  #build the replace string
  my $includefile = $1.'.'.$2;
  my $replacestring = "(* $& *) \n";
  open my INCLUDEHANDLE, "<", $includefile or die $!;
  $replacestring += do { local $/; <INLCUDEHANDLE> }

  # I am lost at this point
}

#this is dirty but it works
#close file for read
close FILEHANDLE;
#open file for write
open FILEHANDLE, ">", $file or die $!;
print FILEHANDLE $string;
#close file for write
close FILEHANDLE;
```

Internet bro-fist for help cleaning up my file read/write operations and for stripping the (* header information *) form the contents of file2 before writing it to file1 like so:

```
file1
code code code
(*%include file2*)
function ( arg : type);
code code code
```

Comment: Also note that I am not looking for a one liner. As I am new to Perl I would actually prefer code that is more easily readable and followed to code that is more efficient or faster.

Comment: So, do you just want to understand the code inside the `if..` statement?

Comment: Happened to see `if ($string =~ m/^%include\s+'(\w+).(PRO)'/gi)` when glancing at your code. That's wrong. `if (//g)` makes no sense. Get rid of that `/g`. It can actually give you incorrect results.

Comment: @Annjawn No, I wrote that part. I would like to finish it (or use a different approach if there is a better one). I need to place $replacestring into file1 after the match, and add (**) to surround the original match in file1.

Comment: @ikegami okay, I assume it is because the global would only be used if I was performing a one line replace? And if I am using the if statement to iterate through individual match occurrences it will not perform as expected with the /g?

Comment: How would you use a regex to a perform conditional statement on each match. I dont think a while would work since the m// and s// return the number of matches...

Comment: hum? regex don't "perform statements", assuming that means "evaluate Perl code".  (You're not talking about `(?{ ... })`, are you?) If *you* wanted to evaluate Perl code for each match, you might use `while (//g)`

Comment: I want to find the first match, which in this case is a file name. I then want to open that file, but this would be conditional on finding a match. I then want to find the next match and open that file, and so on. I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your files are small enough to be slurped, your task is just a fancy string replace:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# function to replace the match with a string (slurped from
# a file mentioned in group)
sub magic_replace {
    my ($m, $g) = @_;
    sprintf "(%s)\nPlease slurp this from '%s'", $m, $g;
}

my $s =<<'EOF'
I should have
slurped
%include file2.ext2;
this from
%include file3.ext3;
file1.ext1
EOF
;

print "---------\n", $s, "---------\n";

$s =~ s/(%include\s([^;]+);)/
   magic_replace($1, $2)
   /egx;

print "---------\n", $s, "---------\n";
```

output:

```
perl 12959116.pl
---------
I should have
slurped
%include file2.ext2;
this from
%include file3.ext3;
file1.ext1
---------
---------
I should have
slurped
(%include file2.ext2;)
Please slurp this from 'file2.ext2'
this from
(%include file3.ext3;)
Please slurp this from 'file3.ext3'
file1.ext1
---------
```

Using a 'callback' function for the replace operation lets you concentrate on (slurping and) constructing the replacement and does all the looping under the hood.

(Both our regex patterns may need some tinkering - your dot, my negligence of spurious whitespace.)

**Update (wrt question in comment)**

If you add a "^" to the pattern, you need to apply the [m modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers).

Comment: I am using the subroutine method now! Brilliant!

Comment: I seem to have hit a snag, the expression does not seem to be evaluating. I am doing the following: `sub build_include_string {
my ($includefilename) = @_; print "test\n"; return my $replacestring = "replace string";}` and I am calling it later with `$count = $string =~s/^%include\s+'(\w+.PRO)'/build_include_string($1)/exgi;` but I do not get any output. (this is just debug code)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some complicated matches to do, you could make do with a one-liner:

```
perl -pi.bak -lwe'$x=qx(cat rep.txt); s/(%include file2;)/(*$1*)$x/g' file1.txt
```

This reads the entire file "rep.txt" into `$x`, which is then inserted after the match.

It is not optimal to rely on `qx()` which is a system call and not portable. Writing an open loop would be better.

Comment: This script is being run on about 200 separate instances of "file1" so a one liner is not really what I am after. What is $x in your example? Because depending on what that is doing `s/(^%include\s+'(\w+).(PRO)'/(*$1*)$x/g $file` might work for me where `my @files = grep {/[.](pas|cmm|ptd|pro)$/i} glob 'C:\users\perry_m\desktop\epic_test\code_pascal\*.*';` and I iterate through the files with `my @files = grep {/[.](pas|cmm|ptd|pro)$/i} glob 'C:\users\perry_m\desktop\epic_test\code_pascal\*.*';`

Comment: If you're going big, go with a program file. There really is no reason not to.

Comment: The code I provided is a snipet of a .pl file I am writing. Is that what you mean by a program file?

Comment: You hit the mark then, I'm at about 200 lines and counting so far.

Comment: But back to my question and previous comment, what does the `$x = qx(cat rep.txt);` line do, and would my adaptation be feasible?

Comment: It stores the output of the system call "cat rep.txt" into `$x`, in other words, the entire file. But I see now that you use windows, so my answer is no good, because `cat` does not exist as a windows shell command.

Comment: So it creates a string representation of the input file, basically.

Comment: @dislexicmofo Yes, a file is just a sequence of characters.